# Digital Download and CD Keys for World of Warcraft Cataclysm

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have been away from WoW for a long time now  but am going be getting back into it. I deleted all the files on my PC still have my active battle.net account and my WoW subscription is still being paid for (I was sure I cancelled the subscription! :( )

What I am hoping will make things clearer for me is this: I will be copying the entire up to date WoW folder from a friend who is playing, which means I only need a CD key in order to upgrade to Cata on my account since Ill already have the entire up to date game installed. Everywhere I look nothing makes it plain to me about whether you receive a CD key with a digital download, and if you do, must you download the entire game before you have access to the key to upgrade?

Or rather, once you have purchased your digital download does your account immediately get upgraded allowing you to cancel the actual download of the game but still upgrade the account? My account is upgraded to WotLK, just need Cata.

Answer (score 5):

I believe, if you buy Cataclysm digitally, the upgrade is automatically applied to your battle.net account. You can install Cataclysm off the CD and then upgrade your battle.net account so you can log in - you don't need to actually download the copy of Cataclysm from battle.net if you buy it digitally, so long as you have the CD.

Comment: Thank you very much for your speedy reply! Now that I know for sure I can go ahead :) I wasn't expecting to get help so quickly here! I really appreciate it :)